# Implementing drag and drop from electron.js to external app

Tags: javascript, html, file, audio, electron

I'm working on an electron.js app that needs to be able to drag and drop audio files from the electron window that are for example represented as a div and drop them to external apps like Audacity etc. Is there any way to implement this?

I've tried to use this code:

`
var dragout = document.getElementById("dragout");

```
    dragout.addEventListener("dragstart", function(evt) {
        // Set the data transfer data with the necessary format
        var fileDetails = "data:audio/mpeg3;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent("test.mp3");
        evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", fileDetails);
    });

    dragout.addEventListener("dragover", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });

    dragout.addEventListener("drop", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        // Here you can handle the dropped file, e.g., initiate a download
        var downloadURL = evt.dataTransfer.getData("DownloadURL");
        window.location.href = downloadURL;
    });
    `
```

but it does not seem to work correctly as it is a download URL instead of an actual file.